# PHP MySQL: while and for loops

Tags: php, mysql

How can I take the output of a while loop and pass it to a for loop?

I get some id from my sql db using while loop. Now, how to pass each id to select query?

For example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $y= $row['c'];
}
```

How can I pass each $y to a select query?

Comment: I think you're going to need to flesh out your question a bit and if you have any code then post that aswell. Otherwise I'd say there's a good chance your question will end up closed.

Comment: @martincarlin87:while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
   $y= $row['c'];} How to pass each $y to select query.

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to perform SQL queries in a loop. In many cases it leads to really bad performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
$Save = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $Save[] = $row['c'];
} 

foreach($Save as $y) {
    // Process $y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the next time, please describe your problem a bit better. we're not supposed to guess.
for more informations: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

And here is an example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
    $IDofRow = $row[0];
    //make new query with the ID you got above

}
```